# How to see the surjectivity of $L^2_{\text{cont}}$ onto the direct integral of Hilbert space representations?

Tags: reductive-groups, langlands-conjectures, eisenstein-series

I've been reading the article [*Forms of $\operatorname{GL}(2)$ from the analytic point of view*](http://www.ams.org/books/pspum/033.1/546600) by Gelbart and Jacquet in [Corvallis](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/pspum/033.1) and am confused on one point.  Let $G = \operatorname{GL}_2$, and $V = L^2(G(\mathbb Q)Z(\mathbb A) \backslash G(\mathbb A),\omega)$, for a central character $\omega$ trivial on $(0,\infty)$.

There is a continuous interwining operator (page 228) $\Phi: V_{\text{cusp}}^{\perp} \rightarrow \mathscr L$ onto a Hilbert space "direct integral" representation $\mathscr L$ of $G(\mathbb A)$, whose kernel is the closure $V_{\text{sp}}$ of the space spanned by characters of the form $\eta \circ \det$ for $\eta^2 = \omega$.  If we define $V_{\text{cont}}$ to be the orthogonal complement in $V_{\text{cusp}}^{\perp}$ of $V_{\text{sp}}$, then $\Phi\rvert_{V_{\text{cont}}}$ is a unitary embedding of $V_{\text{cont}}$ onto a closed subrepresentation of $\mathscr L$.

My question is, how do we actually know that $\Phi$ is *surjective* onto $\mathscr L$ (that is, $V_{\text{cont}} \cong \mathscr L$)?

**Definition of $\mathscr L$**

$\mathscr L$ is described in terms of the family of Hilbert spaces $\mathbf H(s) = \operatorname{Ind}_{N(\mathbb A)Z(\mathbb A)T(\mathbb R)^0}^{G(\mathbb A)} \omega_s$ (page 221).  This is the space of functions $f$ on $G(\mathbb A)$ satisfying a certain norm condition as well as
$$f( n\begin{pmatrix} a \alpha u \\ & a \beta v \end{pmatrix} g) = \omega(a)|u/v|^{s+1/2} f(g)$$
for all $n \in N(\mathbb A)$, $a \in \mathbb A^{\ast}$, $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb Q^{\ast}$, $u,v \in (0,\infty)$.  There is a pairing between $\mathbf H(s)$ and $\mathbf H(-\overline{s})$ given by
$$\langle f_1, f_2 \rangle = \int\limits_K \int\limits_{\mathbb A^{\ast 1}/\mathbb Q^{\ast}} f_1 \overline{f_2}(\begin{pmatrix} a \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix} k) \space d^{\ast} a \space dk.$$
In particular, $\mathbf H(iy) : y \in \mathbb R$ is a Hilbert space representation of $G(\mathbb A)$ with the right translation action.  There is also the intertwining operator $M(s): \mathbf H(s) \rightarrow \mathbf H(-s)$ defined by
$$M(s)f(g) = \int\limits_{N(\mathbb A)} f(wng) dn \tag{$w = \begin{pmatrix} & 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$}$$
which is initially defined for $\operatorname{Re}(s) > 1/2$, but has a meromorphic continuation to make sense for $s \in i \mathbb R$.

Finally, $\mathscr L$ is defined to be the set of measurable functions $a$ from $i\mathbb R$ into $\bigcup\limits_{y \in \mathbb R} \mathbf H(iy)$, such that $a(iy) \in \mathbf H(iy)$ for each $y$, and such that $M(iy)[a(iy)] = a(-iy)$, satisfying the norm condition
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lVert a(iy)\rVert^2_{\mathbf H(iy)} \space dy < \infty.$$

This is a Hilbert space representation of $G(\mathbb A)$ with inner product
$$\langle a_1, a_2 \rangle = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \langle a(iy), a(iy) \rangle_{\mathbf H(iy)} \space dy.$$

The action of $G(\mathbb A)$ comes from combining the right translation actions on each Hilbert space $\mathbf H(iy)$.

**Definition of $\Phi$**

For each continuous function $f$ on $G(\mathbb A)$ satisfying $f(n\gamma zg) = \omega(z)f(g)$ for $n \in N(\mathbb A)$, $z \in Z(\mathbb A)$, $\gamma \in P(\mathbb Q)$, $g \in G(\mathbb A)$ and compactly supported modulo $Z(\mathbb A)N(\mathbb A)P(\mathbb Q)$, we associate the pseudo-Eisenstein series
$$F(g) = \sum\limits_{\gamma \in P(\mathbb Q) \backslash G(\mathbb Q)} f(\gamma g).$$

The space of such functions $F$ is dense in $V_{\text{cusp}}^{\perp}$.  For each $s \in \mathbb C$, the Mellin transform
$$\hat{f}(s) = \hat{f}(g,s) = \int_0^{\infty} f(\begin{pmatrix} t \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}g) \lvert t\rvert^{-s-1/2}d^{\ast}t$$
lies in $\mathbf H(s)$.  If we define $a \in \mathscr L$ by
$$a(iy) = \frac{1}{2}[ \hat{f}(iy) + M(-iy)\hat{f}(-iy)]$$
then the continuous linear map $F \mapsto a$ extends by completion to the intertwining operator on all of $V_{\text{cusp}}^{\perp}$ we call $\Phi$.